# C# the visible property of a control is not changing on event

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, controls

I have a Winform with a combobox with the options Yes or No and this is my event code:

```
    private void cmbYesNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
        if (cmb.Text == "Yes")
        {
            this.button1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Debugging the code, it does correctly go into the correct statement where I am wanting to set the visible property but it doesn't physically change it on the form. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using 'this.button1.Visible' anywhere else in code?

Comment: Do you have other Buttons in that Form?

Comment: while you are debugging, after the visible has been set, did you check if the property has also actually changed ?

Comment: Update, the exact same code works fine on a new clean form, the form I have it on has a lot of controls on including a table and many panels. It's as if there's some parent control which won't allow these to change - is that possible?

Comment: @GuidoG - yes it's property I can see changes in the debugging window, but hasn't on the form

Comment: @Jimi - Yes lots of buttons and controls

Comment: @Markus Meyer - yes that code works fine on a new form

Comment: ok, this means, in current form, there's no other code for changing the 'Visible' property

Comment: What is the parent of this button ? and the parent of this parent ? And so on until you reach the form. Is there any paint method/event on the form or one of the parents ?

Comment: Then `button1` is the wrong Button. You should assign meaningful names to new Controls, as soon as you drop one on a Form. The name usually suggests what that Control is for (its role), so it's easier to identify a Control and determine what it's supposed to do at the same time.